# Best way to combine and keep columns

Tags: r, reshape, rbind

I am trying to reshape a data frame. It has 4 columns: I want to combine 3 of them and keep one. It's probably easier to understand by an example:

This is what it looks like:

```
year    x1  x2  x3
2000    4   3   9
2000    1   4   2
2002    4   3   7
```

This is what it should look like after the reshape:

```
year    x1
2000    4
2000    3
2000    9
2000    1   
2000    4   
2000    2   
2002    4   
2002    3   
2002    7
```

I actually read several examples to combine and transform columns, but the only way I could do that is by writing a function. I am quite sure there is an easier way, so can anyone help me with that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more: `cbind(df[1], x1 = unlist(df[2:4]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
data.frame(year=rep(df$year,each=length(df)-1),x1=c(t(df[,-1])))
```

Or use `melt` from `reshape2`.  But, it will give the result in different order

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df, id.var='year')[,-2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gather()` from the `tidyr` package and `dplyr` you could do (but it will get the result in a different order):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -year) %>%
  arrange(year)
```

You would get:

```
  year variable value
1 2000        x1     4
2 2000        x1     1
3 2000        x2     3
4 2000        x2     4
5 2000        x3     9
6 2000        x3     2
7 2002        x1     4
8 2002        x2     3
9 2002        x3     7
```

If you want to get rid of the variables names and only keep the values:

```
df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -year) %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  arrange(year)
```

You would get:

```
  year value
1 2000     4
2 2000     1
3 2000     3
4 2000     4
5 2000     9
6 2000     2
7 2002     4
8 2002     3
9 2002     7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with base R's reshape:

```
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", varying = 2:ncol(mydf), sep = "")
#     year time x id
# 1.1 2000    1 4  1
# 2.1 2000    1 1  2
# 3.1 2002    1 4  3
# 1.2 2000    2 3  1
# 2.2 2000    2 4  2
# 3.2 2002    2 3  3
# 1.3 2000    3 9  1
# 2.3 2000    3 2  2
# 3.3 2002    3 7  3
```

Or with `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package (but you need to make sure your "id" columns are unique).

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(getanID(mydf, "year"), var.stubs = "x", sep = "var.stubs")
#    year .id .time_1 x
# 1: 2000   1       1 4
# 2: 2000   1       2 3
# 3: 2000   1       3 9
# 4: 2000   2       1 1
# 5: 2000   2       2 4
# 6: 2000   2       3 2
# 7: 2002   1       1 4
# 8: 2002   1       2 3
# 9: 2002   1       3 7
```

You can use `merged.stack(getanID(mydf, "year"), var.stubs = "x", sep = "var.stubs")[, c("year", "x"), with = FALSE]` if you want to drop the ".id" and ".time_1" columns.

Comment: I will be using "splitstackshape" from now on for this kind of tasks. Thanks for the great package.